# What is the best way to store / load local data in iOS?

Tags: ios, database

I am a beginner (student) programmer currently building a course-catalog-like app where I can view courses required for certain specializations within my school.

Currently, I made a seperate data.swift file to store all the data as global and made a bunch of huuuuge arrays. In the main tableview, I just load datas from my data.swift file.

data.swift

```
let data1:[[[[String]]]] = [some datas]
let data2:[[[[String]]]] = [some datas]
let sectionHeaders [[String]] = [some datas]
```

On my tableviewcontroller, I load them up by doing

```
cell = data1[choice1][choice2][choice3]
```

...etc

However, I know that this is NOT how it is supposed to be done, well at least xcode tells me "Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" on my arrays =(, I just don't know any other ways =(

I've actually googled this a little bit and found that some people were recommending plist, some ppl saying sqlite, json, xml and such.

For storing and loading BIG local data, what is the best / most efficient and fastest method?

Thanks!!

Comment: I would add a bit of code regarding how you're loading the data and what you're doing with the data so that we can assist in choosing the best architecture with you.

Comment: JSON is nice simple format, probably the approach of least resistance. You can easily edit the file in text editor. It also offers a nice graceful transition path if and when you choose to fetch the data from a web service rather than building it into your app. One tech you didn't mention was CoreData, Apple's preferred technology for local persistent stores like this, but it might be a bit much to bite off if you're new to development. On the basis of the limited information provided, I'd lean towards JSON.

Comment: @AlexKorean , Added some code!

Comment: @Rob, thanks! I also added some code, would JSON be good with array of array of arrays as well? Thanks!

Comment: @Rob I see, yes,`data1`, `data2` and such are related. Thanks! Will look into JSON Thanks very much!!

Comment: @Rob I am using swift 4

Comment: @Rob Is there other simpler methods as well? JSON seems very difficult...

Comment: An easy approach, if the structure of your data is simple enough, is to put your data in a spreadsheet (maybe using Google Docs) for editing, and export the spreadsheet as CSV or TSV for importing into your app. If you edit your question to describe the structure of your data, we can give you more guidance.

Comment: If you're really trying to represent something as complicated as arrays of arrays of arrays of arrays of strings, as your code snippet suggests, something like JSON or plists probably capture that best (and I lean towards JSON because (a) its human readable; and (b) if and when you get into web services, JSON is the _lingua franca_ of the web. Yes, the JSON is complicated, but only because the structure you're trying represent is so complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that your structure is more complicated, but I wanted to tackle the multiple arrays question. Consider something like:

```
let teachers = ["Larry Fine", "Curly Howard", "Moe Howard"]
let classNames = ["Calculus 101", "Religious Studies 102", "Teaching with Technology in Film and Media Studies 201"]
```

Rather than having multiple arrays, you might have a single structure, e.g.:

```
struct Course: Codable {
    let teacher: String
    let className: String
}
```

You could then represent that in a single JSON structure in a text file, say `courses.json`, like so:

```
[
  {
    "teacher" : "Larry Fine",
    "className" : "Calculus 101"
  },
  {
    "teacher" : "Curly Howard",
    "className" : "Religious Studies 102"
  },
  {
    "teacher" : "Moe Howard",
    "className" : "Teaching with Technology in Film and Media Studies 201"
  }
]
```

In Swift 4, you'd do something like:

```
var courses: [Course]?
```

And then to load a JSON file from your bundle and populate `courses`:

```
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "courses", withExtension: "json")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
courses = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Course].self, from: data)
```

You then end up with a single array of courses which has advantages over the separate `teachers` and `courseNames` arrays. For example, if you want to sort the courses by course name, it makes sure that the course name and teacher name are sorted together.

Now, I know your structure is more complicated than this, so your JSON is likely to get more complicated, too, but I just wanted to illustrate the idea of (a) custom objects; and (b) using Swift 4's new `Codable` protocol and `JSONDecoder` to parse that JSON.

Comment: Wow, awesome!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UserDefaults class. It’s simple and easily accessible. Read the documentation about all the different ways you can retrieve values.

Save Data:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set("Dewan Payroda", forKey: "Name")
```

Retrieve Data:

```
let data = defaults.object(forKey: "Name") 
print(data)
```